# Slow google scripts in spreadsheet/inefficient code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm a complete coding newbie, I've made a spreadsheet checklist, putting an "x" in the first column will make it capture their email and mark down their email so we know who finished the task. However it's awfully slow, can somebody help?

```
    function myFunction() {
    var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var R = ss.getActiveRange().getRow();
    var AColumn = ("A"+R);
    var FColumn = ("D"+R);
    var email = sheet.getRange(FColumn);
    var values = ss.getRange(AColumn).getValues();

    if (values == 'x') 
    { 
    email.setValue(user); 
    }
```

Comment: The logic looks fine to me; script execution takes a noticeable amount of time even for simple scripts, because of how Google servers prioritize it.

Answer (score 0):

@sandwich is correct. Also, based on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices#minimize-calls-to-other-services), You can write scripts to take maximum advantage of the built-in caching, by minimizing the number of reads and writes. Alternating read and write commands is slow. To speed up a script, read all data into an array with one command, perform any operations on the data in the array, and write the data out with one command.

Read the above document for more information and some example code.

You can also check this [blog](http://googleappsscript.blogspot.com/2010/06/optimizing-spreadsheet-operations.html), it explain here how to make your calls fast and efficient as possible.